# Flask-CKEditor's Editing menu - text input fields are not showing up for menu items' dialogue boxes when not using wtf.quick_form or Flask-Bootstrap

Tags: flask, ckeditor

I was able to get the CKEditor properly working when my first Flask project was based on Bootstrap and wtf.quick_form.

Now I'm in the process of builing a new blog application with customized CSS stylesheet and Flask-WTF but NOT Bootstrap. All other formatting went well so far, but when I tried to incorporate CKEditor for WISIWYG, all the manual input fields have disappeared from the dialogue boxes of the CKEditor properties.

Relevant codes in the PREVIOUS blog app

main.py:

```
from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor, CKEditorField
ckeditor = CKEditor(app)
```

new_post.html:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

[other codes...]

{{ wtf.quick_form(form, button_map={'submit':'primary'}) }}
{{ ckeditor.load(pkg_type="full-all") }}
{{ ckeditor.config(name='body') }}
```

The CURRENT project is also adopting the above code except for the bootstrap and wtf.quick_form parts.

The first project works just fine as per screenshot below:
[image]

However, the current project - in the absence of Bootstrap/wtf.quickform - with other relevant codes being the same, the fields somehow disappear when I try to access them:

[image]

ALL properties (Hyperlink, Table, Image, Anchor...) that should have text inputs are having the same issue.

I tried to search through previous troubleshooting resources but it seems that my case is unique?... Or maybe I overlooked something...